# result.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs

I have a problem when I try to run my unit test of my Angular component and the console shows this message. This occurs when the component should be created.

```
result.sort is not a function
```

The message in console

```
ResultComponent › should create                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    TypeError: result.sort is not a function

      45 |   sortResult(result: any[]) {
      46 |     console.log(result)
    > 47 |     let sortedResult = result.sort((a, b) =>
         |                               ^
      48 |       a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      49 |     );
      50 |     return sortedResult;
```

ResultComponent code is here:

```
sortResult(result: any[]) {
    console.log(result)
    let sortedResult = result.sort((a, b) =>
      a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    );
    return sortedResult;
  }
```

I tried to search a solution to this problem but every answer refers to Objects that have not been converted to Arrays. I don't know if this is the same problem.

Comment: Even though typescript wants an array for `result`, when the code is being run it seems like it's not being given one. Please check where it's being used.

Comment: What is the result of your `console.log(result) line no. 46` statement when you get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that you are passing in something other than an array, most likely an object.
Have you checked if it is actually an array?

```
console.log(Array.isArray(result));
```

If It is not an array you can try converting it using the `.from()` method

Hope this helps